# WARNING: xcodeproj is not installed or is not configured properly

Tags: python, xcode, macos, nativescript

My nativescript project won't run, getting the error mentioned above. The Xcode command Line Tools is set.

Things i tried but didn't fix the problem:

```sh
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcode-select --reset
ns doctor ios
```

As you might have guessed, I have Xcode installed from the app store and I've also installed cocoapods and xcodeproj. This is the only warning that I get.

Any suggestions?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/byIaE.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TehVB.png]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Much like the cocoapods install, I had to direct where xcodeproj needed to be installed.

After running this:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin xcodeproj
```

The issue resolved.

Comment: This solved the problem, running fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Didn't work for me. Following your suggestion I tried:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

And it worked. I also had to run:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

In order to get rid of the *"WARNING: Xcode is not installed or is not configured properly."*

Mac OS 13.1 Ventura, M1, Xcode 14.2, tns 8.4.0